# Java generic type restricting class type

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

I am writing a client wrapper for a service. 
Which have given client implementation. Having Two class hierarchy:

1. Account
2. Product

Both classes doesn't share common parent interface. But they while using them they have similar implementation:

Example of piece of code performing

Account service you need following steps of code:

```
 final AccountsCustomBatchRequest content = new AccountsCustomBatchRequest();
 content.setEntries(request);
 final AccountsCustomBatchResponse response =   this.service.accounts().custombatch(content).setDryRun(this.isDryRun)
                        .execute();
return response.getEntries();
```

Similar for product:

```
final ProductsCustomBatchRequest content = new ProductsCustomBatchRequest();
 content.setEntries(request);
 final ProductsCustomBatchResponse response =   this.service.products().custombatch(content).setDryRun(this.isDryRun)
                        .execute();
return response.getEntries();
```

Is there a way to generalize the code? I can't use generic pattern as both those not support common parent class. 
Can I do like:

```
   T extends Account or Product ?
```

Comment: If they have no parent class why are you trying to generalize? If you're using the same methods you should be using a common interface, not a class.

Comment: I would say that its generic enough. There is a point when making it more generic is bad, not saying you have reached that point yet but I would stop, personally.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't show either `Account` or `Product` being used.

Comment: @ReutSharabani But while implementing wrapper. Business logic is nearly duplicated in account and product class.

Comment: Extract it in another class then.

Comment: @Paul May be it was not clear enough. What I mean was both share similar  class hierarchy. Account* and Product*. Example are ProductsCustomBatchRequest vs AccountsCustomBatchRequest. 
ProductsCustomBatchResponse vs AccountsCustomBatchResponse

Comment: @biziclop 
Can you please help me with a smaller example ?

Comment: Generate a utility class with the method you Need and pass the super class of both classes as parameters then cast by detecting the Parameter types using **instance of**

Comment: products and accounts should be passed over to batch processors (that could benefit from Generics). It's hard to make it generic now because you're doing it in the other way around, you're running the batch logic inside products and accounts

Comment: @cahen That is by implementation of third party lib.

Answer (score 0):

They share this method: `custombatch(content)`

I would create an interface containing the `custombatch` method and make something like `T extends custombatchInterface`

Comment: They share same name but not same interface.

Comment: Make them share an interface then. You're the boss. :)

Answer (score 0):

If both classes don't share the same hierarchy, then you can't combine them. A possibly way is to create a new Interface `CustomBatchInterface` with the method `custombatch(content)` and create two `classes` which `extends` the `ProductsCustomBatchResponse` and `AccountsCustomBatchResponse` but also  `implements` your `CustomBatchInterface`.